# Can't add Docky repository

Tags: 19.04, docky

I read some places that you can just install Docky using apt by default but that doesn't work. Tried adding the repository, but it's one of those that won't update because it's unauthorized or something. Is there a repo that works with Ubuntu 19.04 for Docky?

EDIT:
@user535733

```
> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable [sudo] password:
> This ppa is currently used for builds of release builds of
> docky and plank.  More info:
> https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ubuntu/stable Press [ENTER]
> to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
> 
> Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease Hit:2
> http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                  
> Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease             
> Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release            
> Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease            
> Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5
> kB]      Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates
> InRelease               Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> cosmic-updates InRelease              Ign:9
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu disco InRelease     
> Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease  
> Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu disco Release
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] Reading package lists... Done    
> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu
> disco Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details.
```

You know, just you're usual can't update repo error.

Comment: "doesn't work" and "unauthorized or something" don't tell us enough to give you useful advice. We cannot see what you are seeing unless you show us the command and the full output. To copy-and-paste terminal output into your Question is very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docky-core PPA doesn't have a **disco** release. Their most current is **artful**. Change your .list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, or look for another, more currently supported PPA.

**Update #1:**

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/apt` # change directory

`grep -i docky sources.list` # search for docky

**If it finds docky, then:**

`sudo pico sources.list` # edit the file

Locate the line that contains **docky**

Change **disco** to **artful**

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>return</kbd> # to save the file

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # exit the editor

You're done.

**If it didn't find docky, then:**

`cd sources.list.d` # change directory

`grep -i docky *.list` # search again for docky

Note the filename when it finds docky

`sudo pico found_filename.list` # edit that filename

Change **disco** to **artful**

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>return</kbd> # to save the file

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # exit the editor

You're done.

Comment: What do I add in sources.list? I'm not too familiar with how to configure that.

Comment: Almost there, I changed it from disco to artful, and the repos updated successfully, but now when I run "sudo apt install docky" it says "Unable to locate package docky". Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so I changed it to xenial and now it says i have unmet dependencies which can't be installed. Maybe it's hopeless. Thanks for the help anyway, I appreciate it! I learned something new in the process at least!